# Making an http request from an http response's header and content

Tags: c#, .net, http, sharepoint

I have learned to use http request (create and Getresponse) methods to get the header and content of a link.

Problem is that, it is not the link that I want, that I get as http response.

There is an authentication page that comes instead. Only when I click the accept button, do I reach the page I want.

So the header and content that I actually get is of the authentication page.

Is there a way I can use this header and content to create ones more http request to get the page that I want?

I need to click the accept button in the background.

Thanks.

Comment: You might have forgotten to use cookies. If you intend to do web automation, you'll have to use that page to login. Or a web API if the website provides it.

Comment: Hi James and Jay, I am using .net framework and c sharp. It is a copyright page that comes first. Only when I click accept will the requested page be displayed. It is a share point site... Will it be suffient if I capture the viewstate and update action as button clicked and request the same page once more?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Fiddler to capture the interaction with the site using a browser. You can then use the Fiddler output as a guide for replicating the same functionality using your code.

If the site is keeping track of whether or not each user has clicked the Accept button on a per-session basis you'll need to replicate that, probably with an HTTP POST. You'll be able to see how to construct that POST, if relevant, from the Fiddler output.

Comment: Hi Ian, I am stuck ... the two buttons on the page are html controls with onclick events. Is it possible to call client side event handler?

Comment: It's possible to replicate the same effect in terms of HTTP requests and responses. If those client-side buttons generate an HTTP request you can create a similar request. Things will get more complicated if the content of that request is based on HTML content received earlier combined with client-side script logic but it should all be possible to do. From the server's perspective it's just a series of HTTP requests and responses.